# Create and loop a column which is based on the difference between a column and a cell

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, calculated-columns

I need to create a column with the difference between a column and a cell (A3) in a loop.

In the picture I would for example like to know impact 1 with the H3 to a H.. = scenario(F3 to F...) - A3  and impact 2= Scenario2(G3...G)-A3 for x years (B3) for example.

I started with an if loop but I struggled to loop the whole column.

```vb
Sub Lab1()

    Dim i As Integer
    If i <= Range("B3").Value Then
    
        Range("H3").Value = Range("F3").Value - Range("A3").Value
    
        Range("J3").Value = Range("G3").Value - Range("A3").Value
    
    End If
    i = 2020 + Range("B5").Value
End Sub
```

[image: The problem shown in excel]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A lot of people are probably downvoting because you haven't provided what you've tried so far. Showing what you've tried so far is one of the steps listed in [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) because it shows that you've put some effort in. To help with your question, for starters, you'll want to use something like `For x = 3 to someOtherNumber` and `Next x` to go through each of the rows, one at a time, with something like `ActiveSheet.Cells(x,6)` for column F.

Comment: Dear Barvobot, thank you for your feedback! Yeah Im a dummy for stack overflow so I  edit the question and I put the code in this section as well to clarify.

Comment: That's rather confusing, what are you actually doing and how does the spreadsheet relate to your code? What is the expected output and how is it derived?

Comment: Dear SJR, I saw my numbers were shifting in excel so I put a new photo on it.  I started to use i as an integer to iterate for every year from E3 and E8. For example, impact 1 in 2020 I used range().value to calculate the value in H3 by using the difference between range(''F3'').value and range("A3").value, but this is only one value.So I would like to know how you could possibly do this with the whole column until the loop should stop in 2025 in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little iffy on where column P from your code comes into play with your screenshot, but this should roughly do what you're looking for I think. Let us know if you run into any issues!

```
Sub loop1()

'define variables to work with
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim interCol As Long, scen1Col As Long, impact1Col As Long
Dim firstRow As Long, lastRow As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim intervention As Long, scenario As Long
Dim i As Long

'define current worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

'define column numbers
interCol = 1 'A
scen1Col = 6 'F
impact1Col = 8 'H

'define start row
firstRow = 3

'end row is the last non-blank cell in Scenario 1 column
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, scen1Col).End(xlUp).Row

'loop from first row to last row
For i = firstRow To lastRow
    
    'define cell to update
    Set rng = ws.Cells(i, impact1Col)
        
    'intervention doesn't change from row to row
    intervention = ws.Cells(firstRow, interCol)
    
    'scenario varies from row to row
    scenario = ws.Cells(i, scen1Col)
    
    'update target cell with calculation
    rng = scenario - intervention
    
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks you very much . I will work on it.  Yes, I m so sorry I shifted the excel sheet accidentally, but it should be J3 = G3-A3.